# What is the number of mappings?

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

It is given that there are two sets of real numbers $A = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_{100}\}$ and $B= \{b_1, b_2, ..., b_{50}\}.$ If there is a mapping $f$ from $A$ to $B$ such that every element in $B$ has an inverse image and
$f(a_1)\leq f(a_2) \leq ...\leq f(a_{100})$ 
Then, what is the number of such mappings?

I have started tackling the problem by supposing that $b_1<b_2<...<b_{50}$ and dividing elements $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{100}$ in $A$ into $50$ nonempty groups according to their order. Now the problem is... How do I compute the number of mappings defined as $f: A\rightarrow B$ given the observations above?

Comment: Why use Real numbers? Any pair of  ordered sets will do.

Comment: In fact, the set of real numbers is ordered

Comment: I understand, but I don't see where you use any properties of Real numbers. Sorry, just asking.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:My idea is to do an order-preserving partition of the set {$1,2,..,100$} into 50 parts, e.g., (1,2,3), (4,5,6,7,..10),..., (98, 99,100). Then every number in the i-th  part would map to $a_i$. I think this takes care of all maps.

This is a matter of balls-in-boxes , i.e., of finding the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+.....+x_{50}=100; x_i \geq 0$, i.e.,it is a matter of counting the number of ordered partitions of the se $a_1, a_2,...,a_{100}$ into $50$ parts, and then $x_1$ is the number of preimages of $b_1$, and  $x_i$ is the number of preimages of $b_i$. So, using the fact that the number of solutions to $$x_1+x_2+....+x_k=n $$ is $(n+k-1)C(k-1)$ , the number of solutions is $$(49+100-1)C(99)=148C99 $$.

Comment: Nope. This is not a problem of simple combinatorics. If you try the solution that you have exposed drawing a sketch in a simpler case with lower cardinality of the given sets, your mappings wouldn't satisfy the properties given. It's much more subtle.

Comment: Where is it wrong? Ah, sorry, I mixed up the cardinalities of the sets, but I think the idea is right. But the basic idea is the same: every subset of 50+ elements in the domain will give rise to a unique map, by ordering the image set. It depends on what the largest element is in the image set.

Comment: So yes, it is more complicated, or different, but still manageable. Choose the largest image for $f(a_{100})$; could be any $b_1,.., b_{50}$.

Comment: You can delete your answer first, and undelete after you finish. Your answer is now in the rewiew quete, and as stated, I have to vote to delete.

Comment: @JohnMa: The delete option seemed to be disabled. Anyway, I rewrote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**
Suppose $f(a_1)=b_{51},$ then there is only $1$ such mapping.
Suppose $f(a_1)=b_{50},$ then there are $\dbinom{50}{1}=50$ such mappings.
Suppose $f(a_1)=b_{49},$ then there are $\dbinom{51}{2}=1275$ such mappings.

Can you see a pattern!

Comment: [Hocky stick identity](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.artofproblemsolving.com%2Fwiki%2Findex.php%2FCombinatorial_identity&ei=yRGSVcCcK4KNuASOjobYDg&usg=AFQjCNEm0ackI8NrrUeu4rHw6DMWqjTeGA) also helps to simplify the answer.

Comment: I don't know if our answers coincide, but my idea was to do an order-preserving partition of the set {$1,2,..,100$} into 50 parts, e.g., (1,2,3), (4,5,6,7,..10),..., (98, 99,100). Then every number in the i-th  part would map to $a_i$. I think this takes care of all maps.

Answer (score 0):

To come up with such a function $f$, you need to decide, for each element  $b_i \in B$, the number $n_i$ of elements of $A$ which are going to map to it. Once these numbers have been chosen, there is only one way to make the function $f$ because of the condition $f(a_1)\leq f(a_2) \leq ...\leq f(a_{100})$. So, how many ways are there to choose the numbers $n_i$? Well...

- Since each element of $B$ needs to have a nonempty preimage, you have the constraint $n_i \geq 1$.
- Since every element of $A$ must map somewhere, you have the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{50} n_i = 100$.

Counting the solutions to a constrained integer equation of this type is a a pretty common problem. Similar questions have been asked before on this website, for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798093/determine-the-number-of-integer-solutions-of-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-x-5-32?lq=1).

Comment: So, are you saying that the solution is $C(49,100)$?

Comment: @ale42: That would be the answer if you had $n_i \geq 0$ instead of $n_i \geq 1$. You're on the right track, but an adjustment needs to be made.

Comment: @MikeF: I don't know if our answers coincide, but my idea was to do an order-preserving partition of the set {$1,2,..,100$} into 50 parts, e.g., (1,2,3), (4,5,6,7,..10),..., (98, 99,100). Then every number in the i-th  part would map to $a_i$. I think this takes care of all maps.